# Disable primary key index in MongoDB and enable it after bulk insterting?

Tags: java, performance, mongodb, bulkinsert

Is it possible to disable primary key index in MongoDB and enable it after bulk inserting?
The reason is performance during heavy bulk insert.
I'm using JAVA.

Comment: performance on the _id field should be negliable, indexes become a problem when they are numerous or complex, this single _id index will not slow your inserts

Comment: As Sammaye says, I doubt the problem is the index.  What does your code doing the insert look like? Can you provide a mongostat output from during the time when the bulk insert is running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot drop `_id` index. See [official documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/#db.collection.dropIndex):

> db.collection.dropIndex(index)
>
> Drops or removes the specified index from a collection. The db.collection.dropIndex() method provides a wrapper around the dropIndexes command.
>
> Note
>
> You cannot drop the default index on the _id field.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what zero323 has mentioned, it is not always a good idea to disable/enable idexes on the already populated collection even if you are doing bulk inserts.

The reasons that in the beginning you have to remove all the indexes that were previously there, insert the data and then redo indexes for previous data and also for the data which was just added with bulk insert.